# Correct Regex for capturing a block of text in a text file with php

Tags: php, regex, xampp

I have 100+ text files containing the text in the following format..

```
Some Clutter...
This text file is written by using GuavaSoft Notepad.
some more info
Required Info: some text here, some text here also, a new line
text on another new line, SOME CAPITAL TEXT, one more new line,
some numbers, some punctuation marks,
some completely empty line to follow


some empty lines with tab-spaces, spaces to follow



ok, this is the end of required info..

some more unnecarry lines


empty line

etc
etc
```

I need to capture/get all the text between "Required Info"  and "info..", spanned on multiple lines.
 I am reading all the file into $str.
The regex I have come up is

```
$pattern = "/Required Info(.+?)info\.\./im";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Now, this is working at http://rubular.com/r/sP26IahrgI But not at my own Local XAMPP. $matches is just showing empty.
I am very new to RegEx and trying to learn along. Is my Regex expression wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `s` flag so `(.+)` will match with newlines too.

```
preg_match('/required info(.+)info\.\./is', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks.. Although I replaced only m with s. Din't notice you have removed ? also. Could you please explain your both changes, ? and m->s.

Comment: See [Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) and [Regex syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).